# How to filter result of a query builder according condition on join?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, query-builder

I created my query builder, with a join and a condition, but the returned result on the joined data is full and is not filtered according to my join condition (group.id = 3).

How to modify my query or entities to get the affiliations and groups filtered accordingly?

Thank you.

**Query in repository**

```
    $affiliationsGroup = 3;
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');
    $query->join('u.affiliations', 'a');
    $query->join('a.group', 'g');
    $query->andWhere('g.id = :group');
    $query->setParameter('group', $affiliationsGroup);
    $query->getQuery();
```

**returned result**

```
[
        {
            "id": 42,
            "name":"user42";
            "affiliations": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "group": {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "group1",
                      }
                   
                },
                {
                    "id": 94,
                    "group": {
                        "id": 3,
                        "name": "group3"
                      
                    },
                   
                }
]
```

**User Entity**

```
 /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Affiliations::class, mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist"})
     * @Serializer\Groups({"student"})
     */
    private $affiliations;
```

**Affiliation Entity**

```
/**
     * @var \Users
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Users", inversedBy="affiliations", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     * @Serializer\Groups({"student"})
     */
    private $user;

/**
     * @var \Groups
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Groups", inversedBy="affiliations")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     * @Serializer\Groups({"public", "student"})
     */
    private $group;
```

**Controller User**

```
   /**
     *
     * Get all users
     *
     * @Rest\Get("/api/admin/users", name="get_users")
     * @Rest\View(serializerGroups={"student"})
     * @param Request $request
     * @return View
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request): View
    {
            //Access repository and service to call function and my query builder
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

While the results might not be as expected, there is nothing wrong with your code. It filters correctly.

To understand what's happening, you should understand the two steps:

1. User 42 ([I see what you did here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#The_Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life,_the_Universe,_and_Everything_is_42)) has at least 1 affiliation in group 3 so is part of the result.
2. Your serializer will serialize the results. And since user 42 has two affiliations, it will serialize them as well.

Since the serializer doesn't know which filters are applied when querying the results, it doesn't apply those filters.

Unfortunately, this is how API Platform works: it doesn't filter nested entities. See [this issue](https://github.com/api-platform/core/issues/2253) for more details/discussion. You can find some dirty tricks to change the behaviour, but when I encountered the same issue in my project, I decided to filter the nested entities in the front end instead.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Yes the result is correct, but how can i do to apply the filter needed on the serelizer ?

Comment: That depends on your use case. Unfortunately, this is how Doctrine/API Platform works: it can't filter nested entities. One solution is to filter nested entities closer to where the results are used.